# ASP.NET temporary disable validators

Tags: asp.net, validation, temporary

I just have started to learn ASP.NET and implementing simple application with one GridView to view and edit records, and one DetailsView to add new records.
I've added some validators for DetailsView and its works nice, but when i edit records in GridView and then try to update, those validators interfere at this moment and prevent me do update record.
What is the best practice to avoid this problem?
I tried to disable validators when i click on Grid's Update button, but it seem that validation occurs before this event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my bad, it is trivial, i found a solution at msdn tutorials:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb426882.aspx